# Can i join cursor results and subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @value NUMERIC

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
FOR

SELECT year
    ,sum(cast([value amount_CIS] AS NUMERIC))
FROM XYZ
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY 1

OPEN db_cursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM db_cursor
INTO @year
    ,@value

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

 SELECT Result.Year
    ,Result.Value
    ,Result.Avgun
    ,Result.Uniqueshop
    ,Y.Growth
FROM (
    SELECT ResVal.yr AS Year
        ,ResVal.Total_Sales_Value AS Value
        ,ResSku.Avg_Skus AS Avgun
        ,ResVal.Unique_Outlet_Count AS Uniqueshop
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 99.99999 PERCENT a.Year AS yr
            ,SUM(cast(A.[Value Amount_CIS] AS NUMERIC)) AS Total_Sales_Value
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT B.RET_CODE) AS Unique_Outlet_Count
        FROM XYZtable A
        INNER JOIN tblABC B ON A.[Ret Code] = B.RET_CODE
        GROUP BY a.Year
        ORDER BY a.Year
        ) ResVal
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 99.99999 PERCENT a.YR
            ,sum(NUMBER_OF_SKUS) / sum(RetailerCode) AS Avg_Skus
        FROM (
            SELECT yr
                ,sum(NUMBER_OF_SKUS) NUMBER_OF_SKUS
            FROM (
                SELECT a.RetailerCode AS RC
                    ,year(a.DATE) AS YR
                    ,count(DISTINCT PRODUCT) AS NUMBER_OF_SKUS
                FROM FactSKU a
                INNER JOIN DIMSkuMaster b ON a.SKUCODE = b.SKUCODE
                --where year(a.date) = 2011 --and month(a.date) = 01 
                GROUP BY year(a.DATE)
                    ,a.RetailerCode
                ) t
            GROUP BY yr
            ) a
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT year(DATE) yr
                ,count(DISTINCT RetailerCode) RetailerCode
            FROM FactSKU
            GROUP BY year(DATE)
            ) b ON a.YR = b.yr
        GROUP BY a.yr
        ORDER BY a.YR
        ) ResSku
    ) Result --Getting Error about incorrect syntax in the below line 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 99.99999 PERCENT year
        ,(
            (
                @value - (
                    SELECT sum(cast([value amount_CIS] AS NUMERIC)) AS Value
                    FROM XYZ
                    WHERE year = @year - 1
                    )
                ) / (
                SELECT sum(cast([value amount_CIS] AS NUMERIC)) AS Value
                FROM XYZ
                WHERE year = @year - 1
                )
            ) * 100 AS Growth
    FROM XYZ
    WHERE year = @year
    GROUP BY year
    ) Y ----- Getting error  incorrect syntax
    ON Result.Year = Y.year

 --select @year,@value

 FETCH NEXT
FROM db_cursor
INTO @year
    ,@value END

CLOSE db_cursor

DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I am trying to join the results of complex subquery with Cusrsor Results using join.
I am getting errors for on using Y a an alias and Result as an alias that it has incorrect syntax.  Can't I use these ? or how can I ? 
And it is also throwing error on order in Y alias.

Comment: Seems like a strange way of doing things. I cannot determine exactly why you run the cursor but most of time a cursor is not needed as SQL runs on sets of  data, but made because an abstraction is taken from another type of code and "translated" instead of reimplemented. Also what is it with the `top 99.9999 percent` in the query? I'd advice you to rethink your entire approach and start small - that would likely reveal the errors as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use variables from cursor in query inside cursor block, there isn't problem about it. Query parser tells you truth, there is only syntax probelm. You missed ON as rquired part of JOIN. Chnage this:

```
group by a.yr order by a.YR )ResSku) Result
```

into this

```
group by a.yr 
order by a.YR) ResSku ON 1=1 --put here some meaningful condition 
) Result
```

I give you one more advice when you are trying to write queries like that. Make it more readable, and you may see the problem on first sight.